# Visual Studio 2012 - Reboot after Designer modified

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I'm programming a simple DialogPropertyValueEditor for a property of a User Control.
So I have three projects in my solution:

- MyUsercontrolProject
- MyUsercontrolProject.Design
- WPFWindowTest

The MyUsercontrolProject.Design contains a WPF window (call it QueryDesigner) that has to be open when the user click the "..." button on the Usercontrol's property in WPFWindowTest.

The problem is that everytime I made a change in MyUsercontrolProject.Design the WPFWindowTest project fails to load the QueryDesigner window with the message:

```
MyUsercontrolProject.Design.QueryDesigner does not have a resource identified by the URI  '/MyUsercontrolProject.Design;component/DesignerFolder/queryDesigner.xaml'.
```

I need to perform a random series of Close/Open/Recompile/Clean to have the window showed.
Can you please help me to solve this issue?